# Copy & replace long strings greater than 255 character

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently developing a script generator using Excel VBA and need to use find & replace text that are greater than 255 characters. I'm using the code below to replace some words in the generated script

```
Sub SingleScripts(qno As String, qvar As String, qtext As String)

Dim LastRow As Integer 
Worksheets("CodeGenerate").Activate
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("single_sample").Range("A1:A5").Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 3, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Replace What:="QNO", Replacement:=qno
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 3, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Replace What:="qvar", Replacement:=qvar
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 3, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Replace What:="QTEXT", Replacement:=qtext

End Sub
```

But when it comes to replacing the question text, it generates a "type mismatch" error. Is there any other method to work around this problem?

Below is the snippet for the bug:

Error message:

[image: error message]

Error line:

[image: error line]

Input that contain a long text at Q110b:

[image: input that contain a long text at Q110b]

Output for generated script:

[image: output for generated script]

The last line cannot be run due to the replace text is more than 255 characters. Thus, one way to work around with this problem is as follow:

```
Sub SingleScripts(qno As String, qvar As String, qtext As String)
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim d As String
Worksheets("CodeGenerate").Activate
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("single_sample").Range("A1:A5").Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 3, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Replace What:="QNO", Replacement:=qno
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 3, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1)).Replace What:="qvar", Replacement:=qvar

d = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 2, 1).Value
d = Replace(d, "QTEXT", qtext)
ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow - 2, 1).Value = d

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact, complete error message, and which line does it happen on?

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, the error message is "Run-time error '13':'. The error happens for the last code line. I've added the image at the question above

Comment: Could you share the calling code, its location, and a brief description? For example, when using cell values to 'feed' the method, if the `qtext` cell contains an error, that's the error message you'll get. Also, the [Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) has more arguments worth considering.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, the qtext cell doesn't contain any error, it is just a plain text but with characters more than 255 chr. It seems that the Range.Replace method is working similarly as CTRL+find & replace (we cannot insert a long string due to the character limit).  Thank you for your attention though. I found one way as a remedy for this problem which is to assign a variable to store the value of cell that I want to make changes and use Replace(var, "text to change", qtext) command inside the subroutine.

Comment: There is no 255 limit on my end. I put 500 characters in the cell and the replacement works fine. Am I missing something? I have rewritten the code to get rid of the occurrences of `Active` and whatnot. Do you want me to post it?

Comment: Yup @VBasic2008, it will be very helpful if you can share the code too. Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

### Referencing Ranges

- Adjust the `LookAt` and `MatchCase` parameters; they don't have default values.

```vb
Sub SingleScripts( _
        ByVal qno As String, _
        ByVal qvar As String, _
        ByVal qtext As String)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("single_sample")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1:A5")
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("CodeGenerate")
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    srg.Copy Destination:=dfCell
    
    Dim drOffset As Long: drOffset = 3 ' ?
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drOffset + 1).Offset(srCount - drOffset - 1)
    
    drg.Replace What:="QNO", Replacement:=qno, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    drg.Replace What:="qvar", Replacement:=qvar, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
    drg.Replace What:="QTEXT", Replacement:=qtext, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```